# changing manager to employee, using not in clause, some minor confusing in using joint commands

Tags: sql, database, select, join, notin

My schema is as follows:

```
EMPLOYEE (fmane, minit, lname, ssn, birthdate, address, sex, salary, superssn, dno), KEY: ssn
DEPARTMENT (dname, dnumber, mgrssn, mgrstartdate), KEY: dnumber.
PROJECT  (pname, pnumber, plocation, dnum), KEY: pnumber.
WORKS_ON (essn, pno, hours), KEY: (essn, pno)
DEPENDENT  (essn, dependent-name, sex, bdate, relationship), KEY: (essn, dependent-name)
```

I want to find the last name and SSN of those managers who DO NOT work on any one of the projects located in Chicago.

Note: I modifited the original question to practice on SQL, so I changed managers to employees

here is what I have so far:

```
  select e.lname
  from Employee e
  where e.ssn not in 
       (select w.essn
        from works_on w, Project p
        where w.pno = p.pnumber
        and p.plocation = 'Cleveland')
```

So basically are my modification correct? also

1. Do I need write e.lname or just lname since people told me if there's only one item I can just simply use lname?
2. The most confusing part when I use NOT IN clause, how do I know when should I use e.ssn or ssn?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `not in (...)` is arguably the easiest to read/understand, but typically performs the worst.

The best performing is typically an outer join filtering on missed joins:

```
select ssn, lname
from Employee e
left join (
    select essn
    from Project p
    join works_on w on pno = pnumber
    where plocation = 'Cleveland') x on essn = ssn
where essn is null
```

This gives the same result as:

```
select ssn, lname
from Employee e
where ssn not in (
    select essn
    from Project p
    join works_on w on pno = pnumber
    where plocation = 'Cleveland')
```

Note how in both approaches, the subquery selects from `Project` first and uses a `where` clause to select Cleveland locations, which gives the optimiser the best chance to use an index (if one exists) on location, and/or do the least work to get the employees that work in them (via an index on `pno` if one exists).

Also note the use on proper joins (whose syntax became partied the SQL standard more than 20 years ago).

---

Regarding qualifying column names with the table name or alias they come from - it's optional if the column is unambiguous, but generally it's good practice to qualify in production code because:

- you don't have to consult the scheme to figure out where the column lives (self documenting)
- if the schema changes so that the column is no longer unambiguous, your query can suddenly break and you might not realise why

Comment: can you write an answer for me using not in? I promise I will accept it

Comment: Thank you so e.lname or lname can be either fine?

Comment: @lin (note further edits) yes just `lname` is OK, because there is only one such column in the tables selected from

Comment: Tjank you! also lastly why must work_on be used, since I only need find location, which is not in work_on

Comment: the part says from works_on w, Project p
        where w.pno = p.pnumber

Comment: why can't i just be from project instead

Comment: Project can't tell use the ssn of those that work on projects. You need project to find the projects that are in Cleveland, then using those keys you need works_on to find the employee sans working on Cleveland projects, then finally you can use that list to find employees other than those in that list.